# Which site is for asking user-related YouTube questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I posted a question (wrongly) onto superuser.com with my YouTube topic.

It's a particular user problem (not related to programming, or API), just a pure end-user question.

Now superuser.com is not suitable for these types, so it immediately became off-topic.

Which Stack Exchange site is the one for this, and similar questions?

To make it more obvious, my question for easier understanding: *[YouTube: upload finished, but 4K is not available](https://superuser.com/questions/1816133/youtube-upload-finished-but-4k-is-not-available?noredirect=1#comment2855060_1816133)*.

Answer (score 5):

[Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) seems like the right place for this question. They even have a [YouTube tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube).

Fair disclosure: I'm not active on that Stack Exchange site, so take this recommendation with a grain of salt.

Comment: On October 30, a discussion on Web Apps about the "site research policy", tagged as FAQ, was resolved. The resolution, posted as an answer and marked as accepted, among other things, states that the site is not a *help desk*. For all reader's convenience, here is the link to the mentioned FAQ: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/88163)

Comment: The broader context of that quote is "Questions that would reasonably be answered by simply opening the tool don’t belong on Web Apps, as the site is not a helpdesk. However, questions that would reasonably be confusing to a beginner who has made the most basic level of effort to understand the issue are welcome." which gives quite a different colour compared to "the site is not a help desk". Selective quoting at its finest.